# Can I move all data from secondary hard disk to another and then change the drive letter?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, windows-8, clone, clonezilla

I am having trouble getting clonezilla to work so wondered. I have a secondary hard drive that has applications and data on it. I need to replace it with a bigger/newer model. If I simply copy the contents of the source drive to the target and then change the drive letter so that the target takes that of the original will this work? I suspect nothing is that easy.

for clarification I am talking about doing this in the context of cut and paste within windows explorer.

Thanks

OS: win8 64bit

Answer (score 1):

yes that will work as long as the secondary drive is not where your mbr/bootsec are at.

You will have to reassign the old volume a new letter first, and then the previous letter will become available to the new drive. as I'm sure you are aware, you do this in the Computer Management -> Disk Management feature.

Comment: Thanks Frank, I wasnt sure if windows behind the scenes would use true paths etc.

Comment: Don't forget System & Hidden files.